# Mysql new rows don't have default value inserted

Tags: php, mysql

```
ALTER TABLE  `songs`
CHANGE  `artist_name`  `artist_name` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT  'N/A'
```

^ So that's my table and the default for artist_name is 'N/A'. I'm using a form to submit data. However, when I submit the data through a form, the row doesn't contain 'N/A' and the value is empty. Anyone know what is going on?

```
$video_id=$_POST['video_id'];
$song_name=$_POST['song_name'];
$artist_name=$_POST['artist_name'];
$movie_name=$_POST['movie_name'];
$language=$_POST['language'];
$oldornew=$_POST['oldornew'];

//inserting data order
$order = "INSERT INTO dhb_dhb.songs
        (video_id, song_name,artist_name, movie_name,language,oldornew)
        VALUES
        ('$video_id', '$song_name','$artist_name', '$movie_name', '$language', '$oldornew')";
```

Comment: Did you submit an empty value via the form? This would overrule the default.

Comment: We need to see your code, especially your `INSERT` code.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to unset the specific `$_POST` key if it's empty, so `NULL` will be inserted which then automatically is assigned the default value. Now you're just inserting a blank string, which is not translated into the default column value, since it isn't `NULL`.

**EDIT** The easiest way to do it then is to use an associative array, containing only the keys/values that are not empty:

```
$data = array('video_id' => $video_id);
foreach(array('artist_name', 'song_name') as $key)
    if(!empty($_POST[$key])){
        $data[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
    }
}

$columns = "`". implode("`, `", array_keys($data)) ."`";
$values = "'". implode("', '", array_values($data)) ."'";
$query = "INSERT INTO table ({$columns}) VALUES ({$values})";
```

This hasn't been tested and values should be tested before inserting (e.g. is `$song_id` really an integer?) but this is the general idea.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. This is what I have in my php file: $artist_name=$_POST['artist_name'];
What should I do with that? I didn't fully get your post.

Comment: And your SQL insert query then is?

Comment: $video_id=$_POST['video_id'];
$song_name=$_POST['song_name'];
$artist_name=$_POST['artist_name'];
$movie_name=$_POST['movie_name'];
$language=$_POST['language'];
$oldornew=$_POST['oldornew'];

//inserting data order
$order = "INSERT INTO dhb_dhb.songs
   (video_id, song_name,artist_name, movie_name,language,oldornew)
   VALUES
   ('$video_id', '$song_name','$artist_name', '$movie_name', '$language', '$oldornew')";

Answer (score 1):

Any user input can be checked to see if it's set, and if not, use a default value of NULL:

```php
$variable = (!empty($_POST['variable'])) ? $_POST['variable'] : NULL;
```

Now calling this in a query will set the default value if `$_POST['variable']` is empty (or unset).

I must caution. Whenever you take user input and put directly into a Database Query as you've done in your code example, you're opening up a serious security vulnerability known as [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Consider sanitizing your user input using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

**EDIT:**

Your code could then be applied by using something like the following:

```php
<?php

$data = array(
    'video_id',
    'song_name',
    'artist_name',
    'movie_name',
    'language',
    'oldornew',
);
$insert_ary = array();

foreach ($data as $val) {
    if (!empty($_POST[$val])) {
        $insert_ary[$val] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$val]);
    }
}

$columns = implode(', ', array_keys($insert_ary));
$values = implode("', '", $insert_ary);
$sql = "INSERT INTO dhb_dhb.songs ($columns) VALUES('$values')";
```

Comment: I have done the following upon your suggestions:

$artist_name = (!empty($_POST['artist_name'])) ? $_POST['artist_name'] : NULL;

$artist_name= mysql_real_escape_string($artist_name);

Does it look right?

Comment: On that note, I'm using $_GET to pass variables from URL. Should I pass those through mysql_real_escape_string too?

Comment: I just tested the code and your code did not work :(


$artist_name = (!empty($_POST['artist_name'])) ? $_POST['artist_name'] : NULL;

Comment: Sadly, PHP NULL isn't the same as SQL NULL. This won't work as the single quotes are always in the query.

Comment: @goldenboy48 That's because of the single quotes, so it would be inserting an empty string value. I've edited my answer to include a real-world example that should work.